# author name while packaging magento extension?

Tags: extensions, magento-1, magento-connect, package

I'm packaging a Magento extension to be submitted to the Magento Connect.

I'm having one confusion though. What should I set the **User** field to in **Authors** section ? 
[image]

The guidelines doc says that *Package using “User Name” not “Screen Name” or the upload will result in an error*.

Now my confusion is that what it is the username they are referring to ?
Is it the First Name + Last name as in the screenshot below ?

[image]

Comment: There is no relation with account information as per my knowledge

Comment: The doc says ... The first user must match the user name of your magentocommerce.com account used to display your extensions on Magento Connect.

Comment: yes Username is email id so email id is same

Comment: So its like I should enter the email id in both "User" and "email" fields ?

Comment: yes...............

Comment: Its showing an error... Invalid or empty login for author#1 if I'm entering the email id of my account on Magento as "User" and "Email" fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've been doing forever and never have an issue with this setup:

- In the Authors, the **Name field** must match the Magento Connect account **Screen Name defined in the Developer Profile**
- The **User field** can be whatever you want it is not related to Magento Connect.
- The **Email field** is the **email defined in Magento Connect Account Information.**